# Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter

Tags: error

Sometimes I got this error in SharePoint 2013. For example when I try to create a new item in some list. Or when I try to add a new column to some list in the list settings page. I got this error only when I am not on the production environment. So If I am home for example.

This is the error:

The page cannot be displayed
Explanation: There is a problem with the page you are trying to reach and it cannot be displayed.

---

Try the following:

Refresh page: Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout may have occurred due to Internet congestion. 
Check spelling: Check that you typed the Web page address correctly. The address may have been mistyped. 
Access from a link: If there is a link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link.

---

Technical Information (for support personnel)

Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217)

Comment: Can you provide the name of your LISTS ? There could be problem with the special characters that you use in the URL that gets filtered in the IIS .

Comment: For example: Tasks, Taken, FVF-Amsterdam. But also when I try to add a new column to my listsettings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the website properties in IIS,

GOTO > Traffic > Filtering

and disable Verify Normalisation.

This setting is preventing your site from displaying pages with escaped characters in the URLs.

[update]

In later versions of IIS it is in the general tab of the website properties, and not under Traffic.

Comment: Hi, I cannot find some option "Traffic" in IIS7. Where can I find it? I am using windows server 2012.

Comment: Looking on technet its on the General tab in your version. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc995081.aspx

Comment: I send it to the system engineer and he change this on the TMG server.